# Firebase Rules not working properly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Here is my data structure in firebase, I have multiple projects under `Projects` tag and each project contains `staff` key holding multiple staffs and again each staff contains `attendance` key with several properties like `OT1` , `OT2` etc. now I want that `OT1` should be hold numeric value only.

see my data structure in image
[image]

and I have tried this rule

```
{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true,
"Projects": {
  "$pid":{
  "staff":{
    "$sid":{
    "attendance":{
      "OT1":{".validate": "newData.isNumber()"}
    }
    }
  }
  }
},
"Empoyees": {
  "$staffid": {
    ".indexOn": "Type",
    "project": {
      ".indexOn": [
        "project2",
        "project1"
      ]
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

but it still allows me to save text data
its not restrict me this statement

```
attendanceRef.child("OT1").setValue("ABCDEFGH");
```

what should I change in rules.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, finally got the mistake.

The rule should be:

```
{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true,
"Projects": {
"$pid":{
 "staff":{
   "$sid":{
     "attendance":{
      "$aid":{  // **this was the missing in my question**
        "OT1":{".validate": "newData.isNumber()"},
        "OT1_B":{".validate": "newData.isNumber()"},
        "OT2":{".validate": "newData.isNumber()"},
        "Total Mins":{".validate": "newData.isNumber()"}
   }
  }
 }
}
}
},
```